# Instagram endpoints for Meta Business Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm really struggling with querying the Instagram Graph API from Meta. I have a business account and an app settled. I managed to extract a valid access token using the following link.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={INSTAGRAM_APP_ID}&display=page&extras={{"setup":{{"channel":"IG_API_ONBOARDING"}}}}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=token&scope=instagram_basic,instagram_content_publish,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights,pages_show_list,pages_read_engagement&state={STATE}
```

This token is valid what was verified using the Access Token Debugger. Now I would like to extract some basic information connected to Instagram account, such as username, posts, etc. How can I do it? I read plenty of documentation however nothing was helpful actually.

For example I tried to query the following endpoint

```
https://graph.instagram.com/v16.0/me?fields=id&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

However I got a BAD REQUEST error with the following message *Sorry, this content isn't available right now*.

I would appreciate any help.